# Ansible parametrized variables in complex data structures on template

Tags: variables, ansible, jinja2

Is there any resolve problem parametrized variables in jinja without "if"?

I have `var_file.yml`:

```
fruit:
  yellow: banana
  green: apple
```

run *`ansible-playbook playbook.yml --extra-vars healthy=fruit`*

playbook.yml:

```
- name: include var
  include_vars:
    file: var_file.yml

- name: debug parametrized variables
  debug:
    var={{healthy.green}}
```

I want in my output fruit in parameter healthy.

is this possible?
in debug vars i see:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
       fruit{
         yellow: banana
         green: apple
         }
(...)
```

Comment: Have you tried `--extra-vars healthy="{{ fruit }}"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: *"Output fruit in parameter healthy. Is this possible?"*

A: Yes. It's possible. Try this

```
- name: debug parametrized variables
  debug:
    var: myfruits.green
  vars:
    myfruits: "{{ lookup('vars', healthy) }}"
```